# Instace Type Change log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

How do I find out when the Instance size was changed using Cloudtrail? e.g. large -xlarge date, user and so on. One of the instance size have been changed and I'd like to find out which user has changed it

Comment: FYI, AWS Config would be a better place to look at the **history** of an instance (eg what configuration it was at a particular time), but it won't show _who_ made the change. For that, you are correct using AWS CloudTrail.

Answer (score 2):

The [Logging Amazon EC2, Amazon EBS, and Amazon VPC API Calls with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/using-cloudtrail.html) documentation states that:

> All Amazon EC2, Amazon EBS, and Amazon VPC actions are logged by CloudTrail and are documented in the Amazon EC2 API Reference.

The Amazon EC2 API Reference shows that the action you're looking for is the one called [ModifyInstanceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceAttribute.html); in your case you should target events that have `"eventName": "ModifyInstanceAttribute"` and have the `instanceType` key in the `requestParameters` object. The identity of the user (or role) that initiated the action is in `userIdentity`.

An example of such event in CloudTrail is:

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:user/my_user",
        "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "accessKeyId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "userName": "my_user",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {},
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
                "creationDate": "2020-11-26T15:49:37Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2020-11-26T16:54:18Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "ModifyInstanceAttribute",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "111.22.33.444",
    "userAgent": "console.ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "instanceId": "i-08999dedafc4xxyyz",
        "instanceType": {
            "value": "t3.nano"
        }
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "requestId": "11111111-2222-472f-ad77-bbeb506b242d",
        "_return": true
    },
    "requestID": "11111111-2222-472f-ad77-bbeb506b242d",
    "eventID": "aaaaaaa-c757-4501-8889-4f9d90720c0c",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```